# How to present a UIAlertController with textfield, but that textfield must not be a first responder?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I want to present a UIAlertController with text field. this is done. but i don't want it to be a first responder. Is there any way to present UIAlertController with textfield, but textfield should not be a first responder?

```
  func showAlertData(data: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let title =  data
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: renameDocumentString, message: renameDocumentMessageString, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField) in
            textField.text = title
            textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textChanged(_: )), for: .editingChanged)
            textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textDidBegin(_: )), for: .editingDidBegin)
        })
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: cancelString, style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (_) -> Void in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: alertButtonOkString, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (_) -> Void in
            if let textfield = alert.textFields?.first {
            }
        })
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.actionToEnable = action
        action.isEnabled = false
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This code is presenting UIAlertController with textfield as responder. I don't want to become it responder while presenting UIAlertController.

Comment: Resign first responder in the present completion block ?

Comment: I tried in block also. but for the first time it is showing keyboard, then it hide it. but i don;t want the keyboard first time also.

Comment: You want to edit text of UITextField of AlertController?

Comment: yes, once we tap on textfield then keyboard should come, not by default

Answer (score 2):

This is not ideal solution, but as per your requirement disable textfield while add in AlertController and again enable after presenting AlertController.

```
 @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in

        //Disable textfield
        textField.isEnabled = false
    }

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true) {

        //Enable textfield
        alert.textFields?.first?.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect solution as per your requirement please refer below code

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addTextField { (textField) in 
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
            alert.textFields![1].becomeFirstResponder()
        })
}

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default)
alert.addAction(okAction)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

self.present(alert, animated: true)}
```